# Saving Data to Firebase Realtime Database -Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I push data to firebase realtime database, data(String istek) is saved as a null. How can I solve it ?

My database: Users/Drivers/İstekler/istek =""

Code:

```
 mistek=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.istekler);
         mGonder =(Button)findViewById(R.id.istekGonder);
         istek=mistek.getText().toString();
        mGonder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                DatabaseReference istekRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Istekler").child(userId);
                String requestId = istekRef.push().getKey();

                HashMap map = new HashMap();
                map.put("istek", istek);

                istekRef.child(requestId).updateChildren(map);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add :

```
istek = mistek.getText().toString();
```

Inside your `setOnClickListener`:

```
mistek= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.istekler);
mGonder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.istekGonder);
mGonder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                DatabaseReference istekRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Istekler").child(userId);
                String requestId = istekRef.push().getKey();
                istek = mistek.getText().toString(); // get the text from EditText here

                HashMap map = new HashMap();
                map.put("istek", istek); // Push ...

                istekRef.child(requestId).updateChildren(map);
```

**Issue:** It was actually **not getting the text** when you click on the `Button`. You'll also need to declare the `EditText` -> `final`.